# Using getUSerMedia AND webkitSpeechRecognition allow access x 2

Tags: audio, webkit, speech-recognition, getusermedia

I am creating a site that uses two types of audio input... getUserMedia and webkitSpeechRecognition. Both functions are working fine but Chrome is popping up it's access security pop-up twice - which makes sense. Does anyone know how to have one access permission  handle both functions?

Cheers SO!

[image: pop-up access]

```
navigator.getUserMedia({audio:true}, gotStream, function(e) {
    alert('Error getting audio');
    console.log(e);
});
```

and...

```
var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to avoid asking for permissions multiple times is to make sure that your web page is using the https url. Then Chrome will remember your permissions and not show the pop-up again.

Answer (score 0):

On Chrome 36 (and possibly earlier ones) I'm getting just one popup bar for both.