# Is webkitSpeechRecognition supported in Android Chrome?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

Can't seem to find a definitive answer to this question.  If I go to https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html using Chrome 38 on Android 4.1.1 it tells me 'Web Speech API is not supported by this browser'. Yet there are references out there implying it works eg [Failure to record audio while using webkitSpeechRecognition on Android Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25920854/failure-to-record-audio-while-using-webkitspeechrecognition-on-android-chrome)

Can anyone clarify please?

Comment: why u need webkit recognizer rather than just a recognizer intent in plain android?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047433/record-save-audio-from-voice-recognition-intent/  check the link if u need BOTH recognition and file-sink on the audio. Dont use webkit if u want both.

Comment: @RobertRowntree I just want to to be able to convert speech to text.  The demo page .../speech.html is saying I can't: if (!('webkitSpeechRecognition' in window)) {
  upgrade();
}.  I only cited the "Failure to record audio..." because it implies that speech to text conversion is possible on Android / Chrome using webkitSpeechRecognition?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html

Comment: soz @Robert if I'm being dense but is that link actually useful if I'm writing an html page as opposed to an android app?

Comment: no, not useful. if you are in android app and you want STT, use the recognizer intent. The results can go back to your webkit window.

Answer (score 0):

fwiw have found that https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html works on a different phone, still Chrome v38 but running Android 4.1.**2** - seems like a fairly trivial difference bt maybe that accounts for it?